# Visual Studio hangs when clicking "Close & Update" in Tabular model

Tags: visual-studio, ssas, tabular, sql-server-data-tools

I am going crazy now with a tabular project in Visual Studio.

When I try to update a table through the Source Data property:
[image: Source Data under Properties]

and then clicking on *Design* and then refresh the query and afterwards clicking on *Home -> Close and Update* the window turns grey and it hangs forever. I have to end the VS process from Task Manager in order to continue working.

There is no extra steps applied or some other logic going on in the M query (autogenerated) but still freezes and will not update the data/columns.

I have also tried doing that from the Partitions window as proposed
[here on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2c90b769-cec1-4503-9905-9cf50db564ff/tabular-model-hangs-when-clicking-quotclose-amp-updatequot?forum=AzureAnalysisServices)
but it still freezes.

Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 version, Update 3

Please save me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution could be to use the *Partitions* window instead of the *Source Data*
It won't freeze that often when clicking "Close & Update"

**Edit:** 
Visual Studion 2017 works much better and since I started using it, I haven't got this bug so thumbs up for fixing it :)

Answer (score 1):

@Pepys My apologies for not posting this as a comment but cant at the moment :(.

I have a few things that you can try:

Adjust your query is SSMS to only send in a sample size of your total records.  If you have 10 years then only populate 1 just to test this out.

Connect to your data in Visual Studio via the SQL Server Object Explorer to verify you can connect to it.

Comment: I have tried to "Close and Update" even when there is no data in the database (structure only) and it still freezes. So it's not about the quantity of data...